# Haskell Test.Framework specify number of tests to run from command line

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, testing, quickcheck, test-framework

This [documentation](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-5.9/test-framework-0.8.1.1/Test-Framework-Options.html#t:TestOptions) implies that `Test.Framework` can be run with command line arguments. There is a function `defaultMain :: [Test] -> IO ()` but also the function `defaultMainWithOpts :: [Test] -> RunnerOptions -> IO ()` which is

> A version of `defaultMain` that lets you ignore the command line arguments in favour of an explicit set of `RunnerOptions`.

I cannot find documentation on how to pass command line arguments, and the error message for unrecognized options only says "unrecognized option". So my question is how to pass the number of test cases to run from the command line when running `cabal test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`defaultMainWithOpts` is not for command line usage: it ignores and suppresses all the command line options. For testing on command line you should use `defaultMain` and `--help` will tell you all the available options like:

```
Usage: cc-test [OPTIONS]
                   --help                                       show this help message
  -j NUMBER        --threads=NUMBER                             number of threads to use to run tests
                   --test-seed=NUMBER|random                    default seed for test random number generator
  -a NUMBER        --maximum-generated-tests=NUMBER             how many automated tests something like QuickCheck should try, by default
                   --maximum-unsuitable-generated-tests=NUMBER  how many unsuitable candidate tests something like QuickCheck should endure before giving up, by default
  -s NUMBER        --maximum-test-size=NUMBER                   to what size something like QuickCheck should test the properties, by default
  -d NUMBER        --maximum-test-depth=NUMBER                  to what depth something like SmallCheck should test the properties, by default
  -o NUMBER        --timeout=NUMBER                             how many seconds a test should be run for before giving up, by default
                   --no-timeout                                 specifies that tests should be run without a timeout, by default
  -l               --list-tests                                 list available tests but don't run any; useful to guide subsequent --select-tests
  -t TEST-PATTERN  --select-tests=TEST-PATTERN                  only tests that match at least one glob pattern given by an instance of this argument will be run
                   --jxml=FILE                                  write a JUnit XML summary of the output to FILE
                   --jxml-nested                                use nested testsuites to represent groups in JUnit XML (not standards compliant)
                   --plain                                      do not use any ANSI terminal features to display the test run
                   --color                                      use ANSI terminal features to display the test run
                   --hide-successes                             hide sucessful tests, and only show failures
```